# hypercorn: client-certificate verification

Tags: python, fastapi, asgi, hypercorn

I'm trying to enable client certificate validation in hypercorn.  If it matters, I'm using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).  The [documentation](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/tutorials/usage.html) directs me to use the `--verify-mode` parameter and states simply:

> SSL verify mode for peer’s certificate, see ssl.VerifyMode enum for possible values.

I tried a few guesses but get a fatal error: "hypercorn: error: argument --verify-mode: Not a valid verify mode"

I poked around a bit and found this code in the [project history](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn/-/commit/11a44aceaf6011d912da121496a8924ccb31dffd):

```
if self.verify_mode is not None:
    context.verify_mode = self.verify_mode
```

So I did this to verify the valid values (Python 3.8):

```
>>> import ssl
>>> context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
>>> context.verify_mode
<VerifyMode.CERT_NONE: 0>
>>> context.verify_mode = 1
>>> context.verify_mode
<VerifyMode.CERT_OPTIONAL: 1>
>>> context.verify_mode = 2
>>> context.verify_mode
<VerifyMode.CERT_REQUIRED: 2>
>>> context.verify_mode = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...ssl.py", line 720, in verify_mode
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).verify_mode.__set__(self, value)
ValueError: invalid value for verify_mode
```

However trying to pass `0`, `1`, or `2` to `--verify-mode` all give the "Not a valid verify mode" error.  I am able to pass these values using `--cert-reqs` with the warning "Warning: Please use verify_mode instead" but it starts and based on the code I see in [config.py](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn/-/blob/master/src/hypercorn/config.py), it seems like this does the  right thing and sets the `SSLContext` `verify_mode` value.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything.  I would expect to be prompted for a client certificate when I do a `GET` in the browser or at least an error since it is set to 'required'.  But instead, I get a good 200 error code response.

I can't find any good examples, tutorials, or documentation about doing this with hypercorn.  Is there something else here that I need to do such as setting some other properties?  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought that `cert-reqs` wasn't doing anything.  However in working on something else, I found that this was a result of phantom processes likely created because I was using the `--reload` flag.  I am now prompted for a client-certificate when the `cert-reqs` option is set to 1 or 2.  I am still getting a warning and I believe the  verify-mode option is not working properly but the underlying behavior seems OK.